# Is there an explanation behind vampires not using glamour for turning?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-blood

In [True Blood S01E10](http://imdb.com/title/tt1226623/), Jorge the Magister chooses the punishment for Bill Compton. As Bill begins (47:50), he is told

> I'd hate to interrupt, but glamour is not permitted.

At the time, I thought it was just to make it more cruel as part of his punishment.

Now I can think of two other events that seem to follow this rule.

- Eddie probably was not glamoured since he wanted to be like the one who was not attractive, and yet still very popular. (s01e09)
- Bill was not glamoured during his time as depicted in his civil war period encounter. (s01e05)

I can't remember this rule from old novels (Lestat), either. Was the stipulation specifically for Bill's punishment? If it's the rule for any act of turning, has there been a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Bill is a bleeding heart in the first few seasons. Most vampires see themselves as predators to weak human prey. Better, different, and don't have the same morals as they used to when human.  They don't see a reason or need to glamour people when turning them. And most Vampires have a sadistic streak in them, so they actually enjoy the panic they incite. It's a result of an over inflated ego, a power play by the Vampire.

Bill though, does not. He is a reluctant vampire at the beginning,  a father, and  sympathetic to human plights. He doesn't see humans as prey. He sees a panicking baby Jessica and his fatherly instincts kick in.

Since this was a punishment, initiated by the very fact Vampire Authority, they wanted to inflict the most pain on Bill as they could. Preventing him from using glamour was part of it. They couldn't care less if Jessica was scared or traumatized by it.

As Bill was attempting to use it, it likely has no effect on the turning. Just like they can use glamour to get around that pesky "You have to be invited in" rule. The Magistrate words a clue. Permitted. Not that it won't work. Not permitting him to use glamour was the same as forcing a childe on him. Punishment. Vampires are normally allowed to turn whom they want at their leisure.

Keep in mind that many vampires use glamour when feeding on strangers simply under penalty of punishment by the Vampire Authority. They would be much happier scaring and killing the people they drink from.

Answer (score 3):

> Was the stipulation specifically for Bill's punishment?

I got that strong impression.

To expand on that, turning someone creates a mutual obligation between the two. I don't think it was something a vampire took lightly. Case in point was [Eric Northman](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Eric_Northman) & [Pam Swynford](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Pam_Swynford_De_Beaufort). She wanted eternal youth and was actively willing to be turned, but Eric took some convincing.

In contrast, [Jessica Hamby](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Jessica_Hamby) did not know what was happening and was terrified. Bill wanted to ease her fear, probably mostly for the sake of his own conscience, but the [Magister](http://trueblood.wikia.com/wiki/Jorge_Alonso_de_San_Diego) would not allow it.

Comment: The point about the bond is one that didn't occur to me, thanks.